# RTL showing 2 cursor

Tags: android, right-to-left

I am facing issue of able to see 2 cursors when I do RTL (Right To Left) programmatically.

Please see below code :

```
 edtUSername.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR);

     btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    edtUSername.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                }
            });
```

Comment: okay ,Use `TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL` . I am not sure

Comment: Its not working as well